# Solving $u_t = (u_x)^{-1}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the pde:
$$u_t = (u_x)^{-1} \quad u(t,x) \geq 0 \text{ for positive real }x,t, \text{ and } u(0,0)=0$$

by separation of variables with $u(t,x) = f(t)g(x)$.

By rewriting with the substitution i get to $f f' g g' =1$. Trying to solve for $f(t)$ I keep $x$ constant so $g g'=c$ and then $ff' = \frac{1}{c}$.

From here though I can't see how to proceed, should I guess a function $f$ to satisfy this and if so how do I go about it?

Comment: You may notice that $ff'=\frac{1}{2} (f^2)'$, same for $g$.

Comment: @GabrieleCaselli so we get $f = \pm \sqrt{2t/c}, \, g= \pm\sqrt{2cx}$, can we then take the positive roots to satisfy the conditions and give us $u = \sqrt{2xt}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u(x,t)=f(t)g(x)$, then $u_t(x,t)=f'(t)g(x)$ and $u_x(x,t)=f(t)g'(x)$.  Hence, we see that

$$u_t=\frac{1}{u_x}\implies f(t)f'(t)=\frac{1}{g(x)g'(x)}\tag 1$$

Since $f(t)f'(t)$ is a function of $t$ only while $\frac{1}{g(x)g'(x)}$ is a function of $x$ only, and since they are equal for all $x$ and all $t$, both $f(t)f'(t)$ and $\frac{1}{g(x)g'(x)}$ must be constant.

Therefore, we denote the constant $C$ and write

$$f(t)f'(t)=C\implies f(t)=\sqrt{2Ct+K_1}$$

and

$$g(x)g'(x)=1/C \implies g(x)=\sqrt{2x/C+K_2}$$

Enforcing the condition $u(0,0)=0$, we find that either $K_1=0$, or $K_2=0$, or $K_1=K_2=0$.

If we set $K_1=K_2=0$, then we find that

$$u(x,t)=2\sqrt{xt}$$

Comment: Is there a reason we can just take the positive roots for $f(t)$ and $g(t)$? Is this just picking one of the solutions from the family?

Comment: We could have chosen the other roots, but we must choose the roots with the same sign since $u(x,t)\ge 0$.  Inasmuch we will end up multiplying $f(t)$ by $g(x)$ it is irrelevant which signs we choose (i.e., $++$ or $--$).

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks for the clear answer

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.